# Convert string to high precision number in matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I have a file with data values of the order 10^(-6).When I try to read it in matlab, it just give me accuracy of 10^(-4).I used like below,

```
[y]=textread('report.txt','%f')
```

I tried to change `%f` to `%0.6f`, but still it does not work.
Then I try to read file as `%s` and use `str2double`, again same result.

0.004586 is just 0.0045
Please help me

Comment: I bet it is just a display format issue, have you tried `format long` ? (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format` to change the precision.

The `format` function affects only how numbers display in the Command Window, not how MATLAB computes or saves them.

View current format:  `get(0,'format')`

Set current format in present session to `long` using: `format long`

Set current format to `long` for successive session using : `set(0,'Format',long)`

`long` format offers 15 digits after the decimal point for double values, and 7 digits after the decimal point for single values.

Type `help format` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Update the format of your number like this:

matlab>> format long