# Matlab Increase The Precision Of Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this

```
steps = [k'       a(1:n)'      b(1:n)'        x'         y'      e(1:n)'];
```

where k, a, b, x, y and e are vectors what i want is when displaying this matrix, the values of its rows will not be displayed in a mantissa and exponent form like this [image]

any help please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to high precision number in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039818/convert-string-to-high-precision-number-in-matlab) and [How to store more than 4 decimal places in an array in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111341/how-to-store-more-than-4-decimal-places-in-an-array-in-matlab).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311520/how-to-display-data-in-matrix-with-with-more-than-4-decimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `format` command:

```
format longG
```

The other options are: `long`, `short`, `hex`, `shortEng`, `compact`, `longEng`. check the following table:

[image]

check the [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).